# Работа с изображением

Tags: изображения, php

```
$image = imagecreatefrompng('result1.png');
$stack_img = $image;
$color = imagecolorallocate($stack_img, 200, 60, 100);
imageSetPixel($stack_img, 2, 2, $color);
imagepng($image, 'result.png');
```

В результате в result.png будет эта точка, но точка должна быть нарисована в `$stack_img`.

Я так понял, в `$image` ссылка на объект, но по факту не должно быть так. В чем подвох? Как создать копию картинки, а не ссылку на нее?

P.S. Через новый imagecreatefrompng не предлагать, хотелось бы другой вариант, используя переменную `$image`.

Answer (score 1):

ImageCreateTrueColor и ImageCopy

Подробнее http://php5.kiev.ua/manual/ru/function.imagecopy.html

Answer (score 0):

```
$w = imagesx($image);
$h = imagesy($image);
$stack_img = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
imagecopy($stack_img, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $h);
```